# d3 v4 pie chart update - data binding

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to update a pie chart that's already been drawn with a new set of data (i.e. load one set of data, draw pie chart, wait a bit, new data, update) but getting some weird issues with bound data that I'm struggling to get my head around.

https://jsfiddle.net/qwq5o0gu/6/

The pie should initially have two items, A and B which are 0.25 and 0.75 of the pie respectively, then the A item should disappear. If I comment out lines 42 and 43:

```
    svg.selectAll('.arc path').data(function(d, i) { return pie(d); });
    svg.selectAll('.arc text').data(function(d, i) { return pie(d); });
```

when the A data is removed I'm left with B being the same size although the data bound to svg and .arc has been updated.
Without doing both of them either the text or the arc don't update. I get that when I update the data bound to the parent svg I'd have to update the child but I'd expect updating .arc would be enough, not any path and text elements under that.

What am I missing?

Comment: So, total sum of first data should be regarded as base data?